# Tangent line for the curve $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$

Tags: curves, tangent-line, implicit-function-theorem

I'm trying to find the tangent line with respect to an arbitrary point. Let $f(x,y) = x^3 +y^3 -3xy$. We can apply the implicit function theorem here, to solve $y(x)$, in otherwords the equation defines this $y(x)$ implicitly. We can solve for $y'$ since this $y(x)$ is differentiable. By the chain
rule$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = f_y$$$$y'=\frac{-f_x}{f_y}=\frac{-3x^2+3y}{3y^2-3x}$$

provided that $y\neq \sqrt{x}$. Is the equation of the tangent line now simply $$y-y_0 = y'(x)(x-x_0)$$

and can we determine the numbers $y_0,x_0$?

Comment: $x_0$ and $y_0$ in your last equation can be any point on the tangent line. You already know that the "arbitrary point" on the curve where you calculate the tangent, so you can use that as $x_0,y_0$. Or are you looking for the equation of the tangent line to the curve that passes through some arbitrary point?

Comment: On some arbitrary point of the curve

Comment: $f(x,y) = x^3 +y^3 -3xy$ is not a curve. Do you want to write $f(x,y) = x^3 +y^3 -3xy = c$, where $c$ is a constant?

Comment: The function should of course be set equal to zero. Then the function should describe the same curve as the equation?

Comment: The tangent cone is $xy=0,$ so, if your definition allows it, the two tangents at the origin are the two coordinate axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just implicitly differentiate $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$ directly; no need to set $f(x,y)$. Doing so gives us

$$
3x^2+3y^2y'-3y-3xy'=0\implies y'=\frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}
$$

as you found. Now, as you noted, the tangent line to any point $(x_0,y_0)$ that satisfies $x_0^3+y_0^3-3x_0y_0=0$ is

$$y-y_0=\left(\frac{y_0-x_0^2}{y_0^2-x_0}\right)(x-x_0).$$

This is really as simple as it can be, since we shouldn't even try to solve for $y$ explicitly in $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$.